# Polymer 2 Tutorials

Tags: e-commerce, polymer-2.x

I'm a total noob working on learning Polymer 2.0. I have everything setup correctly, now it's all about building an app. I'm looking to build an ecommerce app with Polymer.

Can someone point me to any tutorials on building such an app? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely try Google Code Labs.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Web

This one shows you howto create Polymer 2.0 Carousel. Really good stuff - got me started back in the days :)
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-2-carousel/#0

Comment: Just to add to this, there is also a [case study on creating a shop](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/case-study) with Polymer. Whilst this is using Polymer 1 (I expect this will be updated at some point) it will be a helpful read for you.